# Google G-Suite / Youtube

Tags: youtube, google-workspace, gsuite-addons

When I am logged in with my google account and want to listen music over Youtube. I receive the following error message:

"Restricted Access to this video. Try to log in with Your G-Suite Account."

I am logged in with my account, already switched the account. Nothing changed. I am no developer, but damn I want to get listen to music in the shitty times. I hope one of you can help me.

More info: 
- i had a trial subscription for youtube premium, but cancelled it (which hopefully was not the reason why it block some videos)
- this appears totally randomly (no matter what kind of YT-video)
- 4 out of ten videos are restricted and can not be watched

thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try to set up another browser with a custom DNS provider (like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8), maybe this circumvents your company's restrictions.

This is most likely caused by either your company network infrastructure or some software which you have installed locally.

It's known to be caused by DNSCrypt or Forticlient and possibly anything which should filter out NSFW stuff, since this also affects rated music videos.

If nothing helps, there is also a support request that you can upvote:
https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/22992384